# parsing rss feed gives 500 internal server error

Tags: php, parsing, rss, feed

When i try to parse the google rss feed, i'm getting Network error: 500 internal server error in chrome and firefox developer tool. The first portion of downloading rss feed (with curl) works fine.

I found this example at: http://www.joevasquez.info/development/parsing-xml-feeds-with-php-rss-and-atom/#more-63

Can someone point out on what i'm doing wrong? thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (function_exists("curl_init")){
    $ch=curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.joevasquez.info/feed/');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&topic=t&output=rss');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);

    $data=curl_exec($ch);


    curl_close($ch);
    //print($data);

    $doc=new SimpleXmlElement($data,LIBXML_NOCDATA);

    if (isset($doc->channel)) parseRSS($doc);

    function parseRSS($xml){
        $cnt=count($xml->channel->item);
        for ($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){
            $url=$xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
            $title=$xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
            $desc=$xml->channel->item[$i]->description;

        echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a>'.$desc.'<br>';
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Every time PHP generates a 500 error it is accompanied by a useful entry in an error log. Given that the start of your script is direct output an not a `<?php` tag, chances are it's a parse error. Have a look in you web server error logs and report back any messages you find.

Comment: I tried removing the dtd before the <?php and i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: i'm checking the error log now

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to close the bracket after the for loop.

```
for ($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){
     $url=$xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
     $title=$xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
     $desc=$xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
}
```

Comment: i'm still getting the same error. I closed the for loop and I removed all the dtd before <?php.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it to work. The error from the log:

```
Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  parserss()in /home1/aquinto1/public_html/belibook.com/curl/curl3.php on line 17
```

I cut and pasted function parserRSS before it was called and it works fine now.

The following is my modification:

```
$doc=new SimpleXmlElement($data,LIBXML_NOCDATA);

function parseRSS($xml){
    $cnt=count($xml->channel->item);
    for ($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){
        $url=$xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
        $title=$xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
        $desc=$xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
        echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a>'.$desc.'<br>';
    }
}

if (isset($doc->channel)) parseRSS($doc);
```

Thank you both!